# Script for deleting table rows not working in MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to delete a table row from my database with MySQL and PHP. I have searched through my code and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I think I am close to getting it, probably something simple that I'm not realizing.

If I hover over the delete link there is a link showing with the correct ID number of the row to delete. But if I click it, it isn't working. It just refreshes the screen.

This is my code for index.php:

```
<!-- Table -->

<form action="index.php" method="get" id="dispatch">
<div class="col-md-8 column">



     <fieldset>
        <legend>Incident Board (Incidents in red are active)</legend>
         <div class="scroll-bar">
         <table>
             <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Incident #</th>
                 <th>Town</th>
                 <th>Location</th>
                 <th>Incident Type</th>
                 <th>Time/Date</th>
                 <th>Admin</th>
                 <th>Delete Entry</th>
            </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
             <?php


  if( isset($_POST['town']) )
  {
    $town = $_POST['town'];
  }

  if( isset($_POST['location']) )
  {
  $location = $_POST['location'];
  }

  if( isset($_POST['incident_type']) )
  {
  $incident_type= $_POST['incident_type'];
  }

  if( isset($_POST['time_date']) )
  {
  $time_date= $_POST['time_date'];
  }

  if( isset($_POST['admin']) )
  {
  $admin = $_POST['admin'];
  }

  if( isset($_POST['id']) )
  {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  }



    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Database error"); 
    mysqli_select_db($db, 'cad');  
    $result= mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `cad` ORDER BY `time_date` DESC LIMIT 20"); 


  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

  $town     = $row['town'];
  $location    = $row['location'];
  $incident_type     = $row['incident_type'];
  $time_date = $row['time_date'];
  $admin    = $row['admin']; 
  $id    = $row['id']; 

echo "


                    <tr>
                        <td class=\"id-center\">
                            ".$id."
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ".$town."
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ".$location."
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ".$incident_type."
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ".$time_date."
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ".$admin."
                        </td>


                        <td>
                        <a href=\"delete.php?id=$id\" name=\"delete\" value=\"$id\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-default center-1\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></a>
                        </td> 


                        </tr>";
    }

  mysqli_close($db);


  ?>

             </tbody>
             </table> 
                </div>
             </fieldset>
             </div>
             </form>

<!-- End -->
```

This is my delete.php code:

```
<?php

    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("cad", $dbhandle);

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM cad WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']."");
    header('location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_GET);exit;` on `delete.php` and see what you are getting.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using MySQLi in index.php, but then using mysql in delete.php?

Comment: i think your delete button is actually submitting the form, i.e. refreshing the form and the link is never followed. what happens if you manually go to delete.php?id=xx

Comment: delete.php is open to SQL injection. Just sayin'.

Comment: Also, better hope no bots crawl the page or everything will be deleted (once you get it working). Just sayin'.

Comment: Also, is `ID` really caps in your table, or is it `id`?

Comment: mysql_query("DELETE FROM e2teams WHERE ID = ".$_GET['id']."") or die(mysql_error());  try to check with this if you are getting any error in this syntax

Comment: Hitesh Mundra helped me and I got it working thanks to him! See his answer below that I marked as solved. @BitwiseCreative, can you explain further on the SQL injection vulnerability and what you meant about the bots crawling the page?

Comment: If the webpage can be accessed by anyone (no login required). Then when a bot crawls your page (google search bot for example) it will crawl (access) all the links on the page. This includes all the delete links.

Comment: @Jeemusu, thanks for the tip. This website I'm making is only going to be used by about 10 people who I work with. It's not going to be open to the public so it will have a login system. But lets say Google were to crawl the page, what's the worst case scenario (besides anyone being allowed to delete an entry)?

Comment: If it's not open to the public you won't have a problem. Worst case scenario is the bot visits all your delete links, deleting the content from your database.

Comment: @Jeemusu What's the best way you think I should fix that issue?

Comment: @huth2349 You could set the href to `href="#"` and instead use javascript to redirect the user on the click event. The best way would be to just make sure your pages are restricted to users who are logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql is deprecated, instead of this use mysqli

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$con=mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password,"cad");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries 
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM cad WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']."");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```